# Verifying POI Digital signature

Tags: java, apache-poi, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have recently implemented digital signing and validation of office documents using the apache POI library. I am now looking to add verification to this so I can prove that the document was signed by a trusted user. I have tried the following code but with no success I think as the call to "getSigningCertificateChain" is empty but im not sure how to get this to load properly so the signature will be there? this is my current code:

```
    pkg = OPCPackage.open(Dir, PackageAccess.READ);

    sic = new SignatureConfig();
    sic.setOpcPackage(pkg);
    SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
    si.setSignatureConfig(sic);
    isValid = si.verifySignature();

    X509Certificate x509a = (X509Certificate) sic.getSigningCertificateChain().get(0);


    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\myCer.cer");
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
    PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
    x509a.verify(pk);
```

anyone had any luck with implementing this.

Comment: Did you try reading [the Apache POI unit tests around document signatures](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/TestSignatureInfo.java?view=markup)? The [encryption section on the website](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) covers the basics, but the unit tests are probably the best for full details

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the certificate from the chain based on the issuer Common Name = {myCer.cer} Common Name, then try to verify it

```
PublicKey pk = selectedIssuedCertificate.getPublicKey();
x509a.verify(pk);
```

I hope this could help